# php mysqli not returning value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is the code that is giving me a problem:

```
$letter = $_POST['artistButton'];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Generic` WHERE `songName` LIKE '$letter%'");
$row    = $result->fetch_array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $Artist = $row['Artist'];
    $songName = $row['songName'];
    $Duration = $row['Duration'];
    $URL = $row['URL'];
    $Genre = $row['Genre'];
    echo "<input type='submit' value='$songName' name='artistButton'>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

The statement is correct I saved it to a variable and printed it to the screen, then ran it from the database and it printed the results I wanted so it definitively is not that. For some reason though it is not displaying. I am guessing it has something to do with something I messed up converting from mysql to mysqli. Thanks -Sam

Comment: remove that superfluous `$row = $result->fetch_array();` below `$result` and try it again

Comment: Mysqli wihout prepared statements,you started well.

Comment: That was pretty retarded by me, but still doesnt work

Comment: So you have a connection to the db?

Comment: Yep connection is fine I already checked that.

Comment: and add a parameter inside `fetch_array()` = `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, and are you sure its on a leading `%`? not `%$letter%`, and tip: use prepared statements, its mysqli anyway

Comment: MYSQLI_ASSOC worked actually thanks bumped the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly some codes are cut, but try to remove that extra:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

And use:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Since you're interested on associative indices anyway.

Important note: Since you're using `mysqli_*`, use its parameterized queries instead. Don't directly use `$_POST` values on the query.

```
$letter = "{$_POST[artistButton]}%";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `Generic` WHERE `songName` LIKE ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $letter);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Artist = $row['Artist'];
    $songName = $row['songName'];
    $Duration = $row['Duration'];
    $URL = $row['URL'];
    $Genre = $row['Genre'];
    echo "<input type='submit' value='$songName' name='artistButton'>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```